# Rails permissions: different types of permissions to different models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, authorization

I'm in the middle of rewriting some Rails 3 application logic, and I want to pick your brains about my DB modeling.

In my app, a User can have access to a Page, Group and a Picture. This is pretty easy to do as polymorphic associations:

```
class Permission < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :resource, :polymorphic => true 
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :permissions
end

class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :permissions, :as => :resource
end

# the same for Page and Picture
```

However, those permissions also need to have different types, for example AdminPermission, CollaboratorPermission, OwnerPermission. How would I go about doing that? I want to be able to do this:

```
p = Page.first
u = User.first
u.admin_permissions.create(:resource => p) 

# should return AdminPermission class, not just Permission
per = User.first.permissions.first 
# should return Page
per.resource
```

My question is: How can I model this? Would it be better just to make a Permission class per object, instead of doing all this in a single class? Is there a smart way of doing this? I'm not a big fan of using the role/auth plugins for Rails, as they rely on a user being a specific role. Here, the role changes with the permission. A user can be an admin of a Group, but a Collaborator on an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to roll-your-own authorization, you can look into [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) and Ryan Bates [comments](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/147) about how to define different abilities for different users for different projects. You can read it for full details, but it involves overriding the current_ability method.

```
# in controller
def current_ability
  @current_ability ||= Ability.new(current_user, current_project)
end

# in Ability class
def initialize(user, project)
  if user.admin_for_project?(project)
    can :manage, :all
  else
    can :read, :all
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I looked into CanCan, and it will probably solve my problem. However, what if I wanted to roll out my own?

Comment: Well, there are several (pro) [Railscasts](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=authorization%20from%20scratch%20rails&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Frailscasts.com%2Fepisodes%2F385-authorization-from-scratch-part-1&ei=ZxmUUMGdI5C_0QHRxIHgBA&usg=AFQjCNHy1cXDtRcNUrnBL2F9ekXCfX3UHA) on that topic. But here's another [link](http://everydayrails.com/2011/10/06/rails-authorization.html) that might help.